# Save and load ListView Items with images

Tags: vb.net, listview, save, load

I am writing an app in VB.net, and I am using ListView to store some data. I need to save this list of item and their images when the form is closed and load it again when the form is opened again.

```
Private Sub Form3_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim myWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(myCoolFile)
    For Each myItem As ListViewItem In ListView2.Items
        myWriter.WriteLine(myItem.Text) '// save item text.
    Next
    myWriter.Close()
End Sub

ListView2.View = View.List
    If IO.File.Exists(myCoolFile) Then '// check if file exists.
        Dim myCoolFileLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myCoolFile) '// load your file as a string array.
        For Each line As String In myCoolFileLines '// loop thru array list.
            Dim lineArray() As String = line.Split("#") '// separate by "#" character.
            Dim newItem As New ListViewItem(lineArray(0)) '// add text Item.
            ListView2.Items.Add(newItem) '// add Item to ListView.
        Next
    End If
```

¿What is the best way to save and load this list and their images?, here is the code what im using for create the items:

```
Dim item1 As New ListViewItem
            item1.Text = My.Settings.name_download
            ImageList2.Images.Add("Image1", Image.FromFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\xylithed\covers\maldita_castilla2.png"))
            item1.ImageKey = "Image1"
            ListView2.Items.Add(item1)
```

I need to save the "Image.FromFile" and load it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB Save/Load image location in listview items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311679/vb-save-load-image-location-in-listview-items)

Comment: Please do not repost the same question over and over.  You can (and should) edit your old one to add more clarity.  For instance, the first block seems to have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: The first block is the system to save the items in listview2, but are just saving the text, and not the images.

Comment: Your problem is loading or saving the items?

Comment: Loading and saving, with this code when i save the items just show the text, not the images..